# Load textures from another class in android

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm working on a game for android, using libgdx and IntelliJ. In this game I have two 'screens', these screens use the same texture for their background, this is how I load them:

```
    Texture backgroundTexture;
    public static Sprite backgroundSprite;

    backgroundTexture = new Texture("textures/background.png");
    backgroundSprite = new Sprite(backgroundTexture);
```

This is done in both screens, so my question is, can I load these texture in another class, then use them in both screens somehow, I feel like that would be the way to do it, am I correct? If I'm on the right track, how should it be implemented?

Comment: You could make a "Textures" class. Just initialize the texture variables just as you did there. Make sure you make those variables public and static like this `public static Texture backgroundTexture = new Texture("textures/background.png")`. I think that should be enough info, if you want I can make this an official answer and put all the code.

Comment: Yeah, if u do that I will accepts it as answer, I would appreciate it! (I cant accept a comment as answer, or?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AssetLoader on your own way to load assets. It's nothing special just a class, which is called when the application starts, because the fact is that you should avoid to load assets, when everything is running. It would be just a simple class with static things.

```
public class AssetLoader {

    public static Texture myBackgroundTexture;

    public static void Load() {
        myBackgroundTexture = new Texture("mybgs/my_bg_texture.png");
    }
```

Let's call AssetLoader.Load() when the application start, and you can reference everywhere to your things like:

```
Texture thisScreenBg = AssetLoader.myBackgroundTexture;
```